# Mockito Mock not returning the defined value

Tags: java, mockito

I was on to write some test code for a Facebook API wrapper, however, Mockito seems not be working as expected:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<200> but was:<400>
```

my test class has a definied Mock by Annotation

```
    @Mock
private FacebookAPIWrapper facebookAPIWrapper;
```

with init in the @Before

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

and the test failing is:

```
    @Test
public void testSchedulerWithInvalidEntry() {
    GenericResponseWrapper genericResponseWrapper = new GenericResponseWrapper(200, null);
    Mockito.when(facebookAPIWrapper.createNewPost("invalidToken", "123", "invalid")).thenReturn(genericResponseWrapper);
    FacebookAPIWrapper test = new FacebookAPIWrapper();
    GenericResponseWrapper testAnswer = test.createNewPost("invalidToken", "123", "invalid");
    assertEquals(200, testAnswer.getStatusCode());
}
```

My guess is that I understood Mockito the wrong way. Shouldn't Mockito overwrite the instance of the wrapper here?

I also tryed a spy, didn't work as well.

The installed Mockito is the maven group mockito-core in the version 2.15.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're mocking a separate object.

```
@Mock
private FacebookAPIWrapper facebookAPIWrapper;
```

Then you are using the `test` object instead of the mocked `facebookAPIWrapper`, please check if using the mocked `facebookAPIWrapper` object will work as expected.

```
@Test
public void testSchedulerWithInvalidEntry() {
    GenericResponseWrapper genericResponseWrapper = new GenericResponseWrapper(200, null);
    Mockito.when(facebookAPIWrapper.createNewPost("invalidToken", "123", "invalid")).thenReturn(genericResponseWrapper);
    GenericResponseWrapper testAnswer = facebookAPIWrapper.createNewPost("invalidToken", "123", "invalid");
    assertEquals(200, testAnswer.getStatusCode());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was really a misunderstanding on my side :)