# Why does my method keep on working after I verify it was called in junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to test the following method:

```
public void transactionToBN() {

        List<CustomerDelivery> list = getListOfArticleByStatusA();
        ...
        ...
        if (!list.isEmpty() || list != null) {

            Hashtable<String, Order> docIds = new Hashtable<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                try{
                    ...Some functionalities..

                }catch(Throwable t){
                    countNumId++;
                }
            }
            if (!docIds.isEmpty())
                orderTransfer(docIds);
        }
        
    }
```

My test:

```
@Test
    public void canDoTransactionToBN() {
        customerDelivery = new CustomerDelivery();
        customerDelivery.setCD_COM1("1");
        List<CustomerDelivery> customerDeliveries = new ArrayList<>();
        customerDeliveries.add(customerDelivery);
        Hashtable<String, Order> docIds = new Hashtable<>();
        CustomerDeliveryService spy = Mockito.spy(CustomerDeliveryService.class);

        //when
        Mockito.doReturn(customerDeliveries).when(spy).getListOfArticleByStatusA();
        Mockito.doNothing().when(spy).orderTransfer(docIds);
        spy.transactionToBN();

        Mockito.verify(spy).orderTransfer(docIds);
    }
```

So I am basically just trying to test if orderTransfer() was called. Problem that I run into is that I get a null pointer for a method that is called inside of orderTransfer(), which is something I don't want to test with this unit. I tried .doNothing() so that the code wouldn't keep on going but for some reason it does. Is there something wrong in the way I am trying to verify the methods call or maybe does the code from the whole page, instead of just transactionToBN(), get called?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mockito Mock not returning the defined value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49230677/mockito-mock-not-returning-the-defined-value)

Comment: @maio290 Not really, since I am using my spy object for everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've only stubbed orderTransfer when it's called with exactly `docIds`. I'd assume that it's being called with something that isn't `docIds`, so it's still using the un stubbed method.

Try replacing the stub with `Mockito.doNothing().when(spy).orderTransfer(any());`

There's more detail on argument matchers (`any()`) here https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html